# Reading regexes from file, in Python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to read a bunch of regexes from a file, using python.

The regexes come in a file `regexes.csv`, a pair in each line, and the pair is separated by commas. e.g.

```
<\? xml([^>]*?)>,<\? XML$1>
peter,Peter
```

I am doing

```
detergent = []
infile = open('regexes.csv', 'r')
for line in infile:
    line = line.strip()
    [search_term, replace_term] = line.split(',', 1)
    detergent += [[search_term,replace_term]]
```

This is not producing the right input. If I print the `detergent` I get

```
['<\\?xml([^>]*?)>', '<\\?HEYXML$1>'],['peter','Peter']]
```

It seems to be that it is escaping the backslashes.

Moreover, in a file containing, say

```
<? xml ........>
```

a command `re.sub(search_term,replace_term,file_content)` written further below in the content is replacing it to be

```
<\? XML$1>
```

So, the `$1` is not recovering the first capture group in the first regex of the pair.

**What is the proper way to input regexes from a file to be later used in `re.sub`?**

When I've had the regexes inside the script I would write them inside the `r'...'`, but I am not sure what are the issues at hand when reading form a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no issues or special requirements for reading regex's from a file.  The escaping of backslashes is simply how python represents a string containing them.  For example, suppose you had defined a regex as `rgx = r"\?"` directly in  your code.  Try printing it, you'll see it is displayed the same way ...

```
>>> r"\?"
>>> '\\?'
```

The reason you `$1` is not being replaced is because this is **not** the syntax for group references.  The correct syntax is `\1`.

Comment: I see. I think I have got confused about this a couple of times. For some reason at http://www.regexr.com/ they use `$1` instead of `\1`. There is where I usually go to learn and test my regexes.

Comment: Sorry, but I am seeing an issue independent of the `$1` vs `\1`. When the replacement regex is `<\? xml\1>` is it writing `<\? xml ...>` in the file. That backslash is appearing in the file instead of only the `?`.

Comment: @myfirsttime1 ... exactly what are you expecting `\?` to do in the replacement pattern other than return `\?` ?  Are you wanting to print whether there was a `\\` in the input or not? In that case you need to be capturing it in a group as well

Comment: Sorry, maybe I am confused about regex. I thought `?` needs to be escaped since it is also used to make quantifiers lazy. But maybe it only needs to be escaped if one needs a `?` right after a quantifier to mean a question mark and not modifying the quantifier.

Comment: @myfirsttime1 A **replacement** pattern does not have "quantifiers"